# Rails has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

A user can create organization and then he can make other users as moderators to his organization. Below method shows how the organization is created.

```
def create                                                   
  @organization = current_user.organizations.build(organization_params)

  # Confirm organization is valid and save or return error   
  if @organization.save!
    # New organization is saved                              
    respond_with(@organization) do |format|                  
      format.json { render :json => @organization.as_json }  
    end
  else
    render 'new', notice: "Unable to create new organization."
  end
end
```

How should I create moderators for the organization. I tried using has_many through but it failed. Can somebody help me?

**Update**

Organization Model

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :moderators
  has_many :users, :through => :moderators
end
```

UserModel

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   enum role: [:user, :moderator, :organization, :admin]
   after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

   def set_default_role
     self.role ||= :user
   end

   # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
   # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

   has_many :moderators
   has_many :organizations, :through => :moderators
 end
```

Moderator Model

```
class Moderator < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :organization
end
```

When I create new organization my organization user_id is nil?

Answer (score 0):

Take look at has and belongs to many relation http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many since one user can be moderator for many organization and organization can have many moderators. Also instead of calling `@organization.save!` you should call `@organization.save` because now it will throw error if save would be unsuccessful. You want to have boolean as result of save so your condition works properly